# Writing super long string csv header

Tags: java, string, csv

I have to write out a CSV file and the header has like 100 fields. 
At this moment, I am writing that in a

```
private static final String HEADER = "header1, header2, header3, ...., header100";
```

It works, but it is very messy and hard to read.

Any neater way that I should try?

UPDATE
I think I will use LinkedHashmap (Key being columnID and value being header1, etc.) to build it. That way, it will be easier to update the field headers if needed.

Comment: Where do you get your data? header1, header2,....

Comment: Use the List<String>?

Answer (score 4):

One trick to clean up the code is to use [`Stream#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) and specify each element on its own row, and then join them together:

```
private static final String HEADER = Stream.of(
        "header1",
        "header2",
        "header3",
        // etc...
).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Of course, if your headers are actually "header1", "header2", etc, you can just generate them from a stream directly:

```
private static final String HEADER =
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
                 .mapToObj(i ->  "header" + i)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, you could use com.google.common.base.Joiner, if that's less ugly to you:

```
HEADER = Joiner.on(", ").join("header1", "header2")
```

Comment: Why not use the standard Java API's String.join instead?